# Jsp page showing source code instead of result

Tags: javascript, validation, jsp, struts, oc4j

I am trying to display a page in struts but when I ran it in OC4J server it is showing `src` code also along with my page.
here is my JSP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld" prefix="display"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>

 <%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy 
 %>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <%
    java.util.Calendar currentDate =java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter= 
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy@HH:mm");
    String dateNow=formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());   

    String username=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("CUserID");

    if(username==null) username="";

    ArrayList levyPayRpt=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("citylist");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("citylist",levyPayRpt);
    int citylist;

    if(levyPayRpt==null) {
       citylist=0;
    } else {
       citylist=levyPayRpt.size();
    }    

  %>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
  <title>Companies By Region/Sectors</title>
  <link href="css/displaytagex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" / >
  <link href="css/boto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" / >

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="js/skins/aqua/theme.css" title="Aqua" />
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/menu_home.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/RegisterCategory.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar_inc.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lang/calendar-en.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/VTFSCommon.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body onload="loading();">
       <html:form action="/LevyPayersByRegionAction.do?methodToCall=getCompByRegion" method="post" >

        <html:javascript formName="LevyPayersByRegion" />

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="head_bgcolor">Claims By Region/Sector</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="padding5px"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top"><table border="0" class="details_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td>Parameters</td>
                          </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top"><table class="field_table" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="height:50px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

                                    <tr>

                                  <td width="11%">From Date:<span class="red12">*</span>

                                                        <html:text property="FDate" name="LevyPayersByRegion" style="width:110px;hight:14px"  readonly="true"/>
                                        <a><img alt="pick a date" align="Center" width="20" height="21" src="images/cal.JPG"  onclick="return showCalendar('FDate','0','%d-%b-%Y',false,false);" class="cursorHand"></img></a>
                                      </td>
                                        <td width="11%">To Date:<span class="red12">*</span>
                                        <html:text property="TDate" name="LevyPayersByRegion" style="width:110px;hight:14px" readonly="true"/>
                                       <a><img alt="pick a date" align="Center" width="20" height="21" src="images/cal.JPG"  onclick="return showCalendar('TDate','0','%d-%b-%Y',false,false);" class="cursorHand"></img></a>
                                              </td>  </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                  <td align="right">Region&nbsp; :<span class="red12">*</span></td>
                               <td>   <html:select property="regionName"
                                               name="LevyPayersByRegion"  style="width:300px;" >
                                                            <html:option value="">-----------------Select--------------------</html:option>
                                                           <html:options name="citylist" />



                                                            </html:select></td></tr>
             <tr>
                                  <td align="right">
                                      Company Sector&nbsp; :
                                      <span class="red12">
                                        *
                                      </span>
                                  </td><td>    <html:select property="sectorName"
                                               name="LevyPayersByRegion"  style="width:300px;" >
                                                            <html:option value="">-----------------Select--------------------</html:option>
                                                           <html:options name="sectorlist" />



                                                            </html:select></td></tr>        


                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>                                             
                                     <!--    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/list_img.jpg" border="0" /></a></td> -->
                                     <!--    NewCal([textbox id],[date format],[show time in calendar?],[time mode (12,24)?])-->

                                        </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="bordertop">
                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="mandatory">* Mandatory Field</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <html:button property="sss" value="Generate" onclick="generateClicked();"  />

                                              <html:button property="btnClear"
                                                                       value="Clear" onclick="clearClicked();" />
                                         <html:hidden name="LevyPayersByRegion" property="hidMode"/>
                                             <input type="hidden" name="mess1" id="mess1" value='<bean:message key="PrintImportLevy.NoRecord"/>' />

                                        </td>
                                      </tr>

                                  </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td valign="top"
                    class="padding5px">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>

       </html:form>
   </body>
</html>                                 
 <script type="text/javascript">    
 function clearClicked(){
  document.forms[0].elements["FDate"].value="";
  document.forms[0].elements["TDate"].value="";
  document.forms[0].action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>'+'/LevyPayersByRegionAction.do?methodToCall=clearSelectedRole';

  document.forms[0].submit();      
 }
 function getSelectFile()
 {
  document.forms[0].action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>'+'/LevyPayersByRegionAction.do?methodToCall=onUserFileSelect';
  document.forms[0].submit();
  }      


 function generateClicked()
 {
    if (validateRequired(document.forms[0])) {
       var fromdate  = document.forms[0].elements["FDate"].value;
       var todate =document.forms[0].elements["TDate"].value;
       var regionName = document.forms[0].elements["regionName"].value;        
       var sectorName=document.forms[0].elements["sectorName"].value;    

       if((comparWithSysDates(fromdate))&&(comparWithSysDates(todate))) {
         if(comparDates(fromdate,todate)) { 
            window.open("reportJSP/PrintClaimByRegion.jsp?fromdate="+fromdate+"&todate="+todate+"&regionName="+regionName+"&sectorName="+sectorName,'classPop', "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=900,height=750,left=100,top=150"); 
        }
      }

     }
  }   

</script>
```

I have configured it struts_config.xml

```
 <forward name="LevyPayersByRegion" path="/levycollection/LevyPayersByRegion.jsp"/>
```

and this is the Action class method

```
public ActionForward LevyPayersByRegion(ActionMapping mapping, 
                                   ActionForm form, 
                                   HttpServletRequest request, 
                                   HttpServletResponse response) {


     VTFSInterface vtfsInteface = new VTFSInterface();
     ArrayList citylist = vtfsInteface.getPhysicalRegionSelect();
     request.getSession().setAttribute("citylist", citylist);
     request.setAttribute("citylist", citylist);
     ArrayList sectorlist = vtfsInteface.getSectorSelect();
     request.getSession().setAttribute("sectorlist", sectorlist);
     request.setAttribute("sectorlist", sectorlist);

     return mapping.findForward("LevyPayersByRegion");
}
```

but when i tried to run it 
i am getting this

```
function validateFloatRange(form)
    { var isValid = true; var focusField = null; var i = 0; var fields = new       Array(); oRange = new floatRange(); for (x in oRange) { var field = form[oRange[x][0]]; if ((field.type == 'text' || field.type == 'textarea') && (field.value.length > 0)) { var fMin = parseFloat(oRange[x][2]("min")); var fMax = parseFloat(oRange[x][2]("max")); var fValue = parseFloat(field.value); if (!(fValue >= fMin && fValue <= fMax)) { if (i == 0) { focusField = field; } fields[i++] = oRange[x][1]; isValid = false; } } } if (fields.length > 0) { focusField.focus(); alert(fields.join('\n')); } return isValid; } function validateByte(form) { var bValid = true; var focusField = null; var i = 0; var fields = new Array(); oByte = new ByteValidations(); for (x in oByte) { var field = form[oByte[x][0]]; if (field.type == 'text' || field.type == 'textarea' || field.type == 'select-one' || field.type == 'radio') { var value = ''; // get field's value if (field.type == "select-one") { var si = field.selectedIndex; if (si >= 0) { value = field.options[si].value; } } else { value = field.value; } if (value.length > 0) { if (!isAllDigits(value)) { bValid = false; if (i == 0) { focusField = field; } fields[i++] = oByte[x][1]; } else { var iValue = parseInt(value); if (isNaN(iValue) || !(iValue >= -128 && iValue <= 127)) { if (i == 0) { focusField = field; } fields[i++] = oByte[x][1]; bValid = false; } } } } } if (fields.length > 0) { focusField.focus(); alert(fields.join('\n')); } return bValid; }
```

along with my jsp page.
i have found that these function are in validator.xml file
how can i remove them or atleast make them disappear while displaying my jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSP page is made for client-side validation, thus using `<html:javascript>` you include javascript on the page used for this type of validation. Remove this tag, or try with its attributes like `dynamicJavascript` or `staticJavascript` to set them to `false`. The default settings is `true`. These attributes are used for configuring whether or not to render the dynamic or static JavaScript.

Comment: thank you very much Roman its went away like magic after i added staticJavascript="false" in my jsp.

Comment: @AshokOgirala You should accept the answer that helped you.